# Google Maps V3 custom controls problem

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map into which I add some custom tooltips using custom overlays: http://goo.gl/M6in

However, sometimes the map will work and sometimes it will appear to be "frozen". I can't drag it, I can't click any of the buttons, etc.

The only clue that I've found is that, if I use setTimeout() to wait for ~ 5 seconds, things work. If I don't, it's a crapshoot.

I'm trying to figure out how I can know when the map is ready to accept these custom overlays, and it doesn't seem to follow any of the typical events. I add these overlays AFTER "bounds_changed" and "tilesloaded" events, but a change must occur even later than that that determines whether the map will be broken or functional.

The problem is, I don't know what that change is and how to detect it. Any ideas?

Comment: When it freezes, you don't have any errors in the console ?

Comment: No, and the custom tooltip is rendered. I just can't interact with the map by dragging or clicking any buttons on it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current documentation:

> Implement an onAdd() method within your prototype, and attach the overlay to the map. **OverlayView.onAdd() will be called when the map is ready for the overlay to be attached.**

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#add